# Acute plane triangle with two sides coinciding with a right triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Below are the two questions:

1) If $T$ is a plane triangle with $x, y < z$ such that $x^{2} + y^{2} > z^{2}$
as side lengths, is $T$ necessarily acute?

2) Is an acute plane triangle $T$ such that

$T$ has all sides of integer lengths

$T$ has exactly two sides coinciding with a right plane triangle but not necessarily of equal length

necessarily equilateral?

Comment: Ok, sorry for the mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first first question can be answered via the Law of Cosines. Given a triangle with side lengths $a,b,c$ and angle $\gamma$ opposite to side $c$, the Cosine Law states:

$$c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos{\gamma}.$$

The identity can be arranged to isolate the cosine term:

$$\cos\gamma=\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}.$$

Thus, if we suppose that $a^2+b^2>c^2$, then it follows that the cosine of the angle must be greater than zero too. That means the measure of the angle must be less than $90^\circ$ :

$$\cos\gamma>0\\
\implies 0<\gamma<\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

Note that if $c$ is the longest side, then the other two relevant inequalities $b^2+c^2>a^2$ and $c^2+a^2>b^2$ will hold true automatically for any triangle. Hence, by adding the assumption $a^2+b^2>c^2$, all internal angles of the triangle must be less than $90^\circ$.

---

As for the second question, the answer is obviously no. All you need to prove it is a counter-example. Here's a 3-4-5 right plane triangle (it has integer side lengths), and as you can see, it wasn't hard to inscribe a non-equilateral triangle:

[image]

Comment: Much appreciated. But how to prove that 2) admits a negative answer?

Comment: @Brian See edit.

Comment: Thanks. But the inscribed triangle looks not like an acute triangle?

Comment: @Brian That's because it's not an acute triangle. I probably should have indicated more clearly that this was only intended as a visual hint.

Comment: @Brian Yes, that is that the question. So what you want to do is draw a diagram like the one I made and try to inscribe an acute triangle. Can you figure out a way to move the vertices in such a way that the inscribed triangle becomes acute?

Comment: AH! SORRY FOR WASTING YOUR TIME! I just found I have raised a wrong question! When I used "an inscribed triangle" then I had in mind that the small inside triangle have two sides coincide with two sides of the big right triangle, not necessarily of equal length.

Comment: Then how can an equilateral triangle have a right angle?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯